# Why do Python's trigonometry functions give different results than my calculator?

Tags: python, math

I was trying to make a simple calculation program for trigonometry with right angled triangles given the possible values of "x", "none", and two others with numbers. I know about the functions math.cos(), math.sin(), etc. but they are giving me different numbers from what my calculator is giving me.Here's an example of some of the code I was trying to use:

```
if hyp == "none" and opp == "x":
    answer = adj * math.tan(ang)
```

After entering the values `None` for hyp, `6` for adj, `x` for opp, and `37` for ang, I receive the value:

```
-289.036
```

On my calculator, the same is met with '4.521'.  Why are they giving different results?

Comment: Hint: Units. Units are important!

Comment: Hint2: The units of the angles aren't degrees.

Comment: I know that. I quote, "since they seem to give clearly different results due to radians/degrees or something of the sort". I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: @ProbablyHuman Then your question should have been "How do I convert angles to radians?"

Comment: @chepner Well then I am sorry that I did not word my question better. I'll keep in mind to do so the next time I ask one.

Comment: Hello Probably Human and welcome to the site. I've gone ahead and edited your question to match how this site expects them to look, you are free to edit it again if you don't like what I've done.

Comment: @MackM. Thank you for the edit suggestion. It's fine. I'll try to make everything I write clearer if I do end up asking anything else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because every computer language uses radians to measure angles when given to trig functions.  All programmers should know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.tan) for the `math.tan` function in Python:

> `math.tan(x)`
>
> Return the tangent of *x* radians

This applies to all the trigonometric functions. You must convert degrees to radians first, with the [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.radians) function:

```
math.tan(math.radians(ang))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = adj * math.tan(math.radians(ang))
```

Python math lib requires radians to work, this conversion above should do the trick